# FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
    * LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
     LOG addons.xpi: startup
     LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
     LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
     LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\115268\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous6866859281964080882webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
     LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
     LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening XPI database C:\Users\115268\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous6866859281964080882webdriver-profile\extensions.json
     LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
     Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
     LOG addons.xpi-utils: Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
     LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
     LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
     LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
     LOG addons.xpi-utils: Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
     LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
     LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
     LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
     LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
     LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
     LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Starting timer
     LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Starting write
     LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Write succeeded
     LOG addons.xpi-utils: XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 15
     LOG addons.manager: shutdown
     LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
     LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
     LOG addons.xpi: Notifying XPI shutdown observers
     LOG addons.manager: Async provider shutdown done
     LOG addons.xpi: startup
     LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
     LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
     LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\115268\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous6866859281964080882webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
     LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
    * LOG addons.xpi: No changes found
JavaScript error: chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml, line 654: aUrl is undefined
```

Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:22:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'

Can someone tell me what error is this? I'm running on Selenium 2.32 and Firefox version 26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that FF26 is not supported in selenium 2.32.
Please upgrade your selenium to [2.39.0](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG).

Comment: okay, what are the Firefox version that support selenium 2.32? cause currently if i am having quite an issue if i upgrade the selenium. is it possible if i down grade the Firefox?

Comment: v2.32.0 supports FF20. You can most probably come by an installer in thy Internets.

Comment: Link seems to be dead.